# Paypal IOS SDK issues (can't communicate with servers)

Tags: ios, paypal, sdk

I am trying to process a paypal payment using the latest IOS SDK 2 - BASICALLY i'm trying to follow the example at -

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md

without much luck.

- Background

I'm in Australia.

I'm using the paypal sdk to take a payment in IOS app. the app then makes a call to a PHP web server that will  validate the paypal payment and then  update a subscription on the PHP server backend.

What I've done and where I'm getting stuck.

I've setup a classic API application.

I've set the production and sandbox environments using -

```
 [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:
     @{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"HIDDEN",
     PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"HIDDEN"}
 ];
```

With the text HIDDEN replaced with the real ones.

I used the following code, that successfully starts the paypal dialog -

```
[PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentSandbox];    
PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
NSDecimalNumber *total_cost = NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"4.30"];  

// Amount, currency, and description
payment.amount = total_cost;
payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
payment.shortDescription = @"test";

// Use the intent property to indicate that this is a "sale" payment,
// meaning combined Authorization + Capture. To perform Authorization only,
// and defer Capture to your server, use PayPalPaymentIntentAuthorize.
payment.intent = PayPalPaymentIntentSale;

// Check whether payment is processable.
if (!payment.processable) {

    [self display_message: @"Payment could not be processed. This can happen for a variety of reasons, i.e. the payment  amount was negative, etc. Please contact us if you believe you have received this message in error."];
    return;
}    

// Create a PayPalPaymentViewController.
PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController;
paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment
                                                               configuration:self.payPalConfiguration
                                                                    delegate:self];    
// Present the PayPalPaymentViewController.
[self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

---

The paypal dialog appears but then displays a "can't communicate with servers error, try again later".

the following appears on the xcode console -

2014-03-25 10:42:22.432  PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error:

```
pp_service_error_json_parse_error - System error. Please try again later. (500) | PayPal Debug-ID: a26da2c300c31 | Details: (
        {
        "ns_error" = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)\" (No value.) UserInfo=0xbadecd0 {NSDebugDescription=No value.}";
    }
).
```

so QUESTION (1) any ideas why this is happening.

and QUESTION (2) after this works and I can make a payment, do I then need to confirm the payment info returned from paypal? i.e. do I -

1. Extract the payment id from the SDK callback.
2. Create a rest app id in paypal in addition to the classic one, and
   then get an auth token via a rest call to payal. without the rest
   app, i don't seem to have the secret key, etc to access the paypal
   rest service.
3. Then use the auth token and id from (1)  to make another rest call
   to get the payal payment info and validate it (i.e. check the amount
   is whats expected etc)?

Hope that makes sense.

PS I find the docs incredibly confusing.

**EDIT:** Ok, so next day without anything changed, i tried running the app again, this time different xcode console error - "invalid client credentials". nowhere in this example at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md does it specify client credentials except for this part  around client ids -

```
     [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:
     @{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"HIDDEN",
     PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"HIDDEN"}
     ];
```

which i've set correctly. are their additional credentials that need to be set before launching paypal ios sdk ui?

Comment: You may be getting blocked if the request isn't over SSL.

Comment: BTW, a much more secure way of going about this is to make the payment call to your server and have that talk to paypal. Any request from the client can be forged, so the only way to know for sure if the payment was successful was if your servers do it.

Comment: If your'e sure that the client_ids are correct (no spaces, you didn't accentually swap sandbox/live, etc.) you should contact support with the debug_id in the console message. They can use it to look up specifically what's happening & make sure there's nothing wrong with your account.